# Adding A Function To Django Built-in Login

Tags: python, django

My Question is How I can Add A Function To Django Built-in Login

I want To Add **get_absolute_url()** Function In User Built-in  Model

**Models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404


class PostLikeToggle(RedirectView):
def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
    slug = self.kwargs.get("username")
    obj = get_object_or_404(User, username=slug)
    return obj.get_absolute_url()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where a model doesn't declare `get_absolute_url`, like `User` hasn't since django 1.7, you can use the `ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES` setting.

```
ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES = {
    'auth.user': lambda u: "/users/%s/" % u.username,
}
```

Docs for this are here; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#absolute-url-overrides

Comment: Thank You That Worked For me